# Send Data Receipt With JSON in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to `JSON` and I need to create an object with the following format.

```
{
    "receipt-data" : "(actual receipt bytes here)"
    "password"     : "(shared secret bytes here)"
}
```

I need to fill the `"(actual receipt bytes here)"` (`NSData` variable), and `"(shared secret bytes here)"` which is a number from iOS. I am confused as to how I can create it.

Comment: JSON cannot be used to send plain binary data. Apple probably requires you to send the data in base64-encoded form or something similar (which converts binary data to printable characters). You should doublecheck this first.

Comment: i am converting the nsdata object to be base64 encoded.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Basically you'd say

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}", receiptDataString, passwordString]
```

If receiptDataString is not an NSString you must convert it to one somehow.  Probably use Base64 encoding.  (Unfortunately, there's no standard/commonly used Base64 encoder/decoder for Objective-C.)

If password is an int and not an NSString, change the second %@ to %d.

Comment: This is really bad advice. You need to properly escape characters for JSON. If the password for example contains a " character then this method will generate invalid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple to do. You create an `NSDictionary` with those `receipt-entry` and `password` objects. You then use any of the available open source JSON frameworks, or the built-in JSON API in iOS5, and serialize the `NSDictionary` into an NSString containing the JSON data.

Don't do it manually. You want the JSON to be properly encoded/escaped. This is what the JSON frameworks do for you.